# no openssl_applink in codeblocks

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, openssl, codeblocks

I read in an other question, if my code shows: no `OPENSSL_Applink` and shuts down, i have to include the `openssl/applink.c` file, my problem is, when i do that, my code doesn't build anymore, and gives me error in the `applink.c` file.
the error is: `'_fileno' was not declared in this scope`

in the next three lines:

```
static int   app_fileno(FILE *fp)   { return _fileno(fp); }
static int   app_fsetmod(FILE *fp,char mod)
{ return _setmode (_fileno(fp),mod=='b'?_O_BINARY:_O_TEXT); }
```

what should i do, to complie and run my code?

I use 32bit windows7, and codeblocks.

Comment: `applink` is part of the OpenSSL utilities. Its not part of the library proper. Its sounds like your project is *not* configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

compile and link applink.c in include/openssl directory with your project
i've tried this and it worked for me
as far as i know, it requires a C function called openssl_applink